# When using SVN, and submitting files to repository, how an "n" number of revision is calculated?

Tags: tortoisesvn

When i submit files to SVN, it shows a certain number ( eg. At revision 5 ). What does this number represent. What does it mean ? ( Pic attached)

[image: How revision is calculated ?]

Comment: read this http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.basic.in-action.html

Comment: that's too much technical to go through for now. Just need to know, in a layman's language, how knowing "revision" number is important for me.

Comment: Why would you not want to understand the tool that you work with (i.e. read or at least skim the svn book)?

Comment: If the "basics" of how Subversion functions are "too technical to go through", then you shouldn't be using it. If you don't want to understand how your tools work, at even the most basic level, why are you asking how the tools work here?

Comment: Oh, and stop logging into WinXP as Administrator. That's just a recipe for disaster. Create another user, put it in the Local Admins group if you need to, but operating as the Administrator account is just a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In layman language :

SVN enable you keep track of all you changes, show you the change and the comment made by the one that check-in.

The version number is the "id" of the change, or the version of the file - meaning if you get the file with version X- you will get the file with all changes till (including) change  "id" X .

I think [this](http://betterexplained.com/articles/a-visual-guide-to-version-control/) link is simple to start with

Comment: but why revision 5 on the very first submission ? It should be "1" on the start.

Comment: Why does it matter what is the start version ? check history to see what are the previous version.

Comment: I don't have any previous version. No history. It shows "revision 5" on start only. Why it says revision 5 . Why not 1 ?

Comment: Because you've made 4 changes to the repository already, whether you realize it or not. Look at the log.